# Sql database update on datagrid

Tags: c#, sql

I'd like to know if it's a bad practice. I have a page of datagrid of 50 rows with about 10 text boxes in each row. Page function is very simple with just a button to update and save in ms sql. When user clicks the button, it takes long time to save. I am using update in a sql loop with a hidden id field id. What is the best way to simply update table?

```
  for (int i=0; i<options_bind.Items.Count; i++) 

 {

 if (((CheckBox)options_bind.Items[i].FindControl("check_Save")).Checked )
     { 
      call sql update one by one here
     }

    }
```

Comment: are you using datatable for binding data to datagridview ?

Comment: DataSet  DS = new DataSet();
 myCommand.Fill(DS, "vendor");
 options_bind.DataSource = DS;  I see that code to bind it, and on save button, it's looping row by row and calling update method. Sometimes, it's so slow that it times out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **SqlCommanBuilder** to bind data to datagridview

```
        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryString, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);

        dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        yourDataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

And then on update event

```
           try
            {
                sqlDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
            }
           catch (Exception exceptionObj)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
            }
```